# libgdx multiplayer - how to handle different screen resolutions

Tags: android, libgdx, render, resolution, multiplayer

I'm making a multiplayer game of air-hockey between android mobiles with libgdx. I already able to connect the two phones with tcp connection and they exchange the locations of each other mallet . 
 The two phones have different resolutions and this causes a graphic problems for example :
 - When in one of the phones the mallet in the same line with the puck in the other phone the mallet is not near the puck .
) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_hockey You can see here what i mean when i say mallet and puck until reading it i called it a tool and a disk)

What i need to do in order to solve it so different screen sized phones can play without trouble one against . 
Here is Additional info that may help :

The sizes of game objects and wall locations are already determined by percents of the screen for example the radius of the mallet is 7 percent of screen's width. Also I send the coordinates between the two phones by float numbers between 0 -1 represent where in the screen for example middle point (0.5  , 0.5). But it don't solves it .

Here are the things relevant to game graphics in my render function :

```
batch = new SpriteBatch();
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
height = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
width = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
camera.setToOrtho(false, height, width);
```

Maybe changing any parameters in this functions may help but i have no idea if i need to change something here .

Thanks to the helpers.

Comment: you're looking for the `StretchViewport` and https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: I'm trying to find a simple example of StretchViewport and don't find it  , if you know one i think an example may help me .

Comment: actually, your problem might be a bit more complicated. The elements in the game should **not depend on the screen size**, they should be defined on their own (the model of the game should determine the size of its objects), and *transformed* to be at a specific place on the screen, and the touch input should be transformed with the inverse. I solved this problem before, but I wasn't using the camera (I kinda reinvented the wheel... easy in 2D, wouldn't be in 3D!)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this solution did not use the `camera` class at all, and thus is kinda subpar in my opinion, but this is what I came up with about a year ago when I had a similar problem.

```
public abstract class BaseScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor
{
    protected int windowWidth;
    protected int windowHeight;

    public BaseScreen() 
    {
        windowWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); //width of screen
        windowHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight(); //height of screen
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height)
    {
        windowWidth = width;
        windowHeight = height;
    }

    public void show()
    {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    public int getWindowWidth()
    {
        return windowWidth;
    }

    public int getWindowHeight()
    {
        return windowHeight;
    }

    public void setWindowWidth(int windowWidth)
    {
        this.windowWidth = windowWidth;
    }

    public void setWindowHeight(int windowHeight)
    {
        this.windowHeight = windowHeight;
    }

    ...

    public abstract void onTouchDown(float pointerX, float pointerY);
    public abstract void onTouchUp(float pointerX, float pointerY);

    @Override
    public final boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
    {
        float pointerX = InputTransform.getCursorToModelX(windowWidth, screenX);
        float pointerY = InputTransform.getCursorToModelY(windowHeight, screenY);
        onTouchDown(pointerX, pointerY);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int     button) 
    {
            float pointerX = InputTransform.getCursorToModelX(windowWidth, screenX);
            float pointerY = InputTransform.getCursorToModelY(windowHeight,     screenY);
            onTouchUp(pointerX, pointerY);
            return false;
    }
}
```

Which uses the following (where `appWidth` is the model width, and the `appHeight` is the model height, aka the size of the world)

```
public class InputTransform
{
    private static int appWidth = 480;
    private static int appHeight = 320;

    public static float getCursorToModelX(int screenX, int cursorX) 
    {
        return (((float)cursorX) * appWidth) / ((float)screenX); 
    }

    public static float getCursorToModelY(int screenY, int cursorY) 
    {
        return ((float)(screenY - cursorY)) * appHeight / ((float)screenY) ; 
    }
}
```

And then I set the proper parameters for the screen's viewport transform, and the projection transform for what draws the objects within the [0,480]x[0,320] grid:

```
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0,  0,  Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()); //init screen to [0,ScreenWidth]x[0,ScreenHeight]
    Resources.batch = new SpriteBatch();
    Resources.normalProjection = new Matrix4().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, 480, 320); //create transform to [0,480]x[0,320] world grid
    Resources.batch.setProjectionMatrix(Resources.normalProjection); //initialize drawing with transform
    Resources.shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(Resources.normalProjection); //initialize drawing with transform
```

But if you *are* using the `OrthographicCamera`, then you really just need to replace `InputTransform` with `camera.unproject()`, and set the camera viewport to `StretchViewport`. Considering the approach I gave above has its limitation, which is that you need to hack it around to actually **move** the camera from the [0,480]x[0,320] grid.

So as per the documentation on the page,

```
private Viewport viewport;
private Camera camera;

public void create() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new StretchViewport(480, 320, camera);
}
```

Or a more complete example on the wiki:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera

Or **most importantly**, an example for using orthographic camera with viewports:

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/12/09/LibGDX-Tutorial-Part-17-Viewports.aspx

```
//copy paste from GameFromScratch:
package com.gamefromscratch;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;

public class mouseproject extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {
   SpriteBatch batch;
   Sprite aspectRatios;
   OrthographicCamera camera; //the camera 
   Viewport viewport; //the viewport

   @Override
   public void create () {
      batch = new SpriteBatch();
      aspectRatios = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Aspect.jpg")));
      aspectRatios.setPosition(0,0);
      aspectRatios.setSize(100,100);

      camera = new OrthographicCamera();
      viewport = new StretchViewport(100,100,camera); //stretch screen to [0,100]x[0,100] grid
      viewport.apply();

      camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2,camera.viewportHeight/2,0); //set camera to look at center of viewport
      Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void render () {

      camera.update();
      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined); //make batch draw to location defined by camera
      batch.begin();
      aspectRatios.draw(batch);
      batch.end();
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose(){
      aspectRatios.getTexture().dispose();
   }

   @Override
   public void resize(int width, int height){
      viewport.update(width, height);
      camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

      Gdx.app.log("Mouse Event","Click at " + screenX + "," + screenY);
      Vector3 worldCoordinates = camera.unproject(new Vector3(screenX,screenY,0)); //obtain the touch in world coordinates: similar to InputTransform used above
      Gdx.app.log("Mouse Event","Projected at " + worldCoordinates.x + "," + worldCoordinates.y);
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
      return false;
   }
}
```